# Google Container Engine does not install docker >=1.5 on cluster creation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

Google Container Engine makes it easy for anyone to create kubernetes clusters on Google's Cloud platform. On top of that, Google Cloud offers a Google Container Registry that enables us to host private docker images.

Problem is, my kubernetes cluster's individual nodes have docker version 1.4.1 installed instead of >=1.5.

```
$ docker version
Client version: 1.4.1
Client API version: 1.16
Go version (client): go1.3.3
Git commit (client): 5bc2ff8
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
```

This meant that I could not deploy containers because the images are hosted on the Google Container Registry. This is a known docker [bug](https://cloud.google.com/tools/container-registry/#pushing_to_the_registry).

```
FATA[0000] Invalid namespace name (project-id), only [a-z0-9_] are allowed, size between 4 and 30
```

How do I install the correct Docker version on instances created using Google Container Engine? Appreciate any responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the question! These are your easiest two options:

1. Replace the hyphens in your project ID with underscores, as is recommended by the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/tools/container-registry/#pushing_to_the_registry) you linked to.
2. Re-create your cluster. As of yesterday, new Container Engine clusters will be at version 0.13.2, which uses Docker 1.5 by default.

You could also SSH to the nodes to manually upgrade and restart Docker, and I can help you do that if you'd like, but the first two options seem preferable.

Comment: Thank you so much! I recreated the cluster to try and recreate the environment and sure enough, I saw Docker 1.5.0. Thanks Alex!